# Selecting part of an extracted ligand

Tags: covid-19, sars-cov-2, pymol

I have the PDB [6LU7](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/6LU7).

- I extracted the ligand using extract lig, org  and then the protein using extract prot, poly.  The ligand has three parts:  02J, PJE, and 010.
- I want to select the 02J and 010 IN A SCRIPT and delete them.

I know how to do it by simply clicking, but want to incluse this in a script.

Comment: Hi @user8338 and welcome. I think what you are asking is PyMol scripting, I suspect Modeller will do something similar. Do you use PyMol/Modeller? If so could you please update and clarify your post accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know that structure way too well —SARS-COV-2 MPro.

In PyMOL command line

```
 remove resn 02J or 010
```

or

```
 cmd.remove('resn 02J or 010')
```

In python

```
 import pymol2
 with pymol2.PyMOL() as pymol:
      pymol.cmd.fetch('6LU7')
      pymol.cmd.remove('resn 02J or 010')
      pymol.cmd.save('6LU7.mod.pdb') 
      #or pdbblock = pymol.cmd.get_pdbstr()
```

From the sounds of it you'd like to make the peptidomimetic a peptide. If you wanted to do the horrid thing of making PJE, the capped side chain glutamine ketamide, into glutamine, the command to rename atoms is a multitude of `cmd.alter('resn PJE and name <atomname>', 'name="<newname>")` followed by a `cmd.alter('resn PJE', 'resn="GLN"')` and lastly `cmd.sort()` to commit the changes. Not pretty, but is all in PyMOL.

Comment: Wow, impressive response - thanks

Comment: And, related, for the structure 6M2N, there are four 3WL ligands, one in each of the four protein chains.  I'd like to remove 3WL in chains B, C, and D, retain chain A ligand, also scripted (not select and remove).  Thanks!

Comment: The selection algebra is listed in https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Selection_Algebra
But basically you want to select based on meeting two criteria so it's an `and`. Namely, `cmd.remove('3WL and not chain A')`

Comment: Typo: `cmd.remove('resn 3WL and not chain A')`